# Adjust size of pie charts

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2

I've made these pie charts:

```
df <- expand.grid(log.var = c(TRUE, FALSE), zone = 1:4)
df$proportion <- c(0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 0.6, 0.2, 0.8, 0.5, 0.5)
df$size = sample(1:20, 8)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(factor(1), proportion, fill = log.var)) + 
   geom_bar(stat = "identity") + coord_polar(theta = "y") + facet_grid(.~zone)
```

[image]

Is there any way of adjusting the size of each pie chart according to the sum of `size` in each `zone`?

Comment: Like `ggplot(transform(df, sum = with(df, ave(size, zone, FUN = sum))), aes(factor(1), proportion, fill = log.var, width = sum)) + ...`?

Answer (score 3):

@lukeA's suggestion is sensible but doesn't quite work:

```
library("ggplot2"); theme_set(theme_bw())
library("dplyr")  ## for mutate()
set.seed(101)
df <- expand.grid(log.var = c(TRUE, FALSE), zone = 1:4)
df <- mutate(df,
   proportion=c(0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 0.6, 0.2, 0.8, 0.5, 0.5),
   size = sample(1:20, 8),
   totsize=ave(size, zone,FUN=sum))

g0 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(1), y=proportion, fill = log.var))
g0 + geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(width=totsize))+facet_grid(.~zone)+
        coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

[image]

The problem here is that the bars are drawn (in rectangular coordinates) in the *middle* of the x-axis; we'd like them to be drawn with their x-coordinates running from 0 to the full width, but I'm not sure how to do that.  The alternative would be to do a bunch of the cumulative proportion/stacking computations by hand (or at least outside `ggplot2`), then use `geom_rect()` ...

Here's how:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(zone) %>%
    mutate(cp1=c(0,head(cumsum(proportion),-1)),
              cp2=cumsum(proportion))

ggplot(df) + geom_rect(aes(xmin=0,xmax=totsize,ymin=cp1,ymax=cp2,
                           fill=log.var)) + facet_grid(.~zone)+
                               coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

[image]