# How to get complete, rather than partial, pie charts using gganimate

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2, pie-chart, gganimate

I have a problem when doing an animated pie chart with `gganimate` and `ggplot`.

I want to have normal pies each year, but my output is totally different.

You can see an example of the code using `mtcars`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)


#Some Data

df<-aggregate(mtcars$mpg, list(mtcars$cyl,mtcars$carb), sum)
colnames(df)<-c("X","Y","Z")

bp<- ggplot(df, aes(x="", y=Z, fill=X, frame=Y))+
geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") + coord_polar("y", start=0)

gganimate(pie, "output.gif")
```

An this is the output:

[image: ![enter image description here]

It works well when the `frame` has only one level:

[image]

Comment: you can reproduce my whole code. I used `mtcars` to create the data.

Comment: Maybe my english is not good, but in my question i ask for a solution of the first plot, not for the second. The second is to show only how it works with one level... I do not know what is your problem with my work. You have not idea of what I am doing with this graphs and data and how they are going to be formated. But of course, you know everuthing

Comment: Sorry @Essberto I actually hadn't understood it right at first - may be because my English isn't perfect neither. I don't pretend to know everything, I'm just trying to guide you getting more people helping you : When I screened your question I thought you had an issue with the second plot that only displays one year, while the first one looks quite nice, and because I couldn't reproduce that seconde one, I just left my first comment. I sincerely apologize if that sounded rude to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ggplot code creates a single stacked bar chart with a section for every row in `df`. With `coord_polar` this becomes a single pie chart with a wedge for each row in the data frame. Then when you use `gg_animate`, each frame includes only the wedges that correspond to a given level of `Y`. That's why you're getting only a section of the full pie chart each time.

If instead you want a full pie for each level of `Y`, then one option would be to create a separate pie chart for each level of `Y` and then combine those pies into a GIF. Here's an example with some fake data that (I hope) is similar to your real data:

```
library(animation)

# Fake data
set.seed(40)
df = data.frame(Year = rep(2010:2015, 3), 
                disease = rep(c("Cardiovascular","Neoplasms","Others"), each=6),
                count=c(sapply(c(1,1.5,2), function(i) cumsum(c(1000*i, sample((-200*i):(200*i),5))))))

saveGIF({
  for (i in unique(df$Year)) {
    p = ggplot(df[df$Year==i,], aes(x="", y=count, fill=disease, frame=Year))+
      geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") + 
      facet_grid(~Year) +
      coord_polar("y", start=0) 
    print(p)
  }
}, movie.name="test1.gif")
```

[image]

The pies in the GIF above are all the same size. But you can also change the size of the pies based on the sum of `count` for each level of `Year` (code adapted from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27771019/496488)):

```
library(dplyr)

df = df %>% group_by(Year) %>% 
  mutate(cp1 = c(0, head(cumsum(count), -1)),
         cp2 = cumsum(count))

saveGIF({
  for (i in unique(df$Year)) {
    p = ggplot(df %>% filter(Year==i), aes(fill=disease)) +
      geom_rect(aes(xmin=0, xmax=max(cp2), ymin=cp1, ymax=cp2)) + 
      facet_grid(~Year) +
      coord_polar("y", start=0) +
      scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,max(df$cp2)))
    print(p)
  }
}, movie.name="test2.gif")
```

[image]

If I can editorialize for a moment, although animation is cool (but pie charts are uncool, so maybe animating a bunch of pie charts just adds insult to injury), the data will probably be easier to comprehend with a plain old static line plot. For example:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Year, y=count, colour=disease)) +
  geom_line() + geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, max(df$count)))
```

[image]

Or maybe this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Year, y=count, colour=disease)) +
  geom_line() + geom_point(show.legend=FALSE) +
  geom_line(data=df %>% group_by(Year) %>% mutate(count=sum(count)), 
            aes(x=Year, y=count, colour="All"), lwd=1) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, df %>% group_by(Year) %>% 
                                summarise(count=sum(count)) %>% max(.$count))) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("black", hcl(seq(15,275,length=4)[1:3],100,65)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Very nice. And thank you for your recommendation, but I need the animated pie charts for what I want. The only thing I am worried  is about the animation package. I would like to do it directly with the gganimate.  But thank you for the solution.

Comment: I agree with _animating a bunch of pie charts just adds insult to injury_

Comment: I think you need to know a little bit more about what i am doing before to write that... But of course, you know everything...

Comment: Sorry @Essberto, I can only guess what you haven't written. And pie charts aren't my piece of cake