# Animated plot with polar coordinates

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I'm trying with ggplot2 to create an animated pie plot.

My data is a bit complex but here is a simplified example :

```
ex = data.frame(cat=c("cat1","cat2","cat1","cat2","cat1","cat2"), f = c(70,30,60,40,50,50), t=c(1,1,2,2,3,3))
ex$t = factor(ex$t)

p = ggplot(ex, aes(x="", y=f, fill=cat, frame=t))+
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) 

gganimate(p, "ex.gif", interval=1)
```

If I display p, it seems ok : [simple png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkh1Q.png)

But the gif is not ok : [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGCnk.gif)

Any idea how to solve this bug ?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453746/how-to-get-complete-rather-than-partial-pie-charts-using-gganimate) post. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The generated `.gif` looks correct to me. Each frame is generated with separate data. Perhaps you are looking for gradually generating pie chart. You should use `cumulative  = TRUE` to build frames cumulative.

The code should be changed to:

```
p = ggplot(ex, aes(x="", y=f, fill=cat, frame=t, cumulative = TRUE))+
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0)
```

Comment: the png image should be one of the gif frames. The pie should be full because numbers all add up to 100. Isnt it ?

Comment: The full pie shows 300. Each observation will add up to  300. If cumulative is TRUE then pie will be full at 3rd frame.